# How to setup WebSphere Liberty as a very simple HTTP Serve to serve files in a directory

Tags: attachment, httpserver, maximo

I need to setup IBM Maximo attachments feature to work with WebSphere Liberty. IBM confirms that WebSphere Liberty is compatible wit Maximo, but does not provide official support.

Bottom line, all I need is to serve files inside a directory through HTTP using WebSphere Liberty. I was wondering how I can do that.

This is a guide that I need to adapt it from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21312993 with WebSphere Liberty instead.

Can anyone guide me through?

Answer (score 0):

IBM HTTP Server (IHS) already installed with Maximo. IHS is a flavor of Apache, so any Apache related doc will work. I configured Maximo doclinks to fall under htdocs so the attachments are available as a web resource. Bottom line, its not clear to me you need to configure WebSphere Liberty for this purpose.